# c# .net 3.5 program asking for .net even through .net 4.x already installed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

Before you try to down vote, I read the other threads about this and none of them helped at all.

I have written a program in c# with .net 3.5 so that most of my clients who have .net 3.5, .net 4.X, or both will be able to use it. Problem is several clients have .net 4.x but do NOT have 3.5 and it keeps asking for 3.5. How do I make this not happen. I want it to run seamlessly on 4.0 OR 3.5.

[image: Make this go away!]
This is what I have right now in my app.config file.

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
 </startup>
```

I need this to not ever come up if they have .net 4.x but do NOT have .net 3.5

Comment: remove the 2nd supportedRuntime line in config and now your program will use .net 4 runtime

Comment: interesting. you probably need primary application which checks for the .net versions installed. then it chooses to run compatible version of your main application.

Comment: Win10 machines have .NET 3.5 available but it is not installed by default.  It is getting long in the tooth.  You don't need our help to fix this, simply click the install link to get it deployed.

Comment: @HansPassant The point of this question as I read it is that the OP's application doesn't need .NET 3.5. It needs either .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0, and the users have .NET 4.0 already, so shouldn't be prompted to install anything else.

Comment: @HansPassant Correct! I feel like it should be easier than it is. I might just have to rewrite my whole program in C++

Comment: Sure, you'll get to figure out how to deploy the C++ runtime support libraries.  No "click here" solution, character-building.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I am still getting that message popping up.

Comment: @hansPassant My program is essential a screen sharing program that used for tech support. It needs to be fast and seamless with as little work as possible on the clients end. I do not want them to have to "wait" for .net 3.5 in load. This should not be a problem. Most clients have one or the other or both.

Comment: What you put in your question works. I just verified it on a Windows 10 machine with a Hello world application targeting .NET 3.5. After removing .NET 3.5, running that shows the message you put in your question. After adding the config file, it works without any prompts. Are you sure you gave the config file the correct name? The `app.config` name is only during development. At runtime it needs `<filename>.exe.config`. Also, did you make sure to wrap everything in a `<configuration>` element?

Comment: @hvd From my tests, removing .net 3.5 does not actually remove it.  I had to manually delete the 2.x folders to properly emulate one of my clients systems.

Comment: also remove the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy entry. for me this works fine on a system without .net 3.5 for a .net 3.5 program. without the supportedRuntime entry for 4.0 I get the message you see.

Answer (score -1):

If you use some features of .NET 3.5, you should install .NET 3.5 alongside with .NET 4.0

**UPDATE**

To be correct: .NET 4 uses a separate framework/CLR, and isn't an update

Comment: This is not what I asked.

Comment: I mean, that you can not achieve what you want, if you use some parts of .net 3.5

Comment: My program works perfectly fine in BOTH. Again, you are not helping.

Comment: Yes, it's by design, if you are targeting .net 4.0 and use .net 3.5 features, you should install both frameworks. You can not avoid this.

Comment: Again wrong. I am targeting .net 3.5 which runs FINE in .net 4. I do not want to have to ask for .net 3.5 install when .net 4 is already running.

Comment: So, your program runs, when .Net 3.5 installed. It's ok. 
If you customers have only .Net 4.0 installed, they need also .Net 3.5 installed.
In newer versions of windows .net 3.5 is installed by default. But, when you install .Net 4.0 in doesn't install 3.5 features.
Probably I misunderstood you, so can you create some solution, that reproduces problem, and share it? It'll be easier to help you :-)

Comment: @YuryGlushkov Not the OP here, but this is trivially reproducible. I just did it with `using System; namespace HelloWorld { static class Program { static void Main() { Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!"); } } }`, in an application targeting .NET 3.5, then uninstalling .NET 3.5 (while leaving .NET 4 installed), and attempting to run that application. It doesn't need any .NET 3.5 features, it works fine with .NET 4's `Console` class, and the application config file can enable it to run on .NET 4.

Comment: And, as I understood, if you target .Net 4.0 it works fine?

Comment: @YuryGlushkov Yeah, applications which target .NET 4 continued to work fine even without a config file.

Comment: @YuryGlushkov If you actually care to help, please re-read the questions since I do not think you understand. My program was written in 3.5 so I could hit as many clients as possible without compatibility problems. Now that more and more windows 10 computers come pre-installed WITHOUT .net 3.5 I want to avoid them having to wait or click more stuff use my support software.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I faced this issue and found no way to create executable, that works with both frameworks at once.

Comment: .NET 4 and greater uses a separate framework/CLR, and isn't an update to earlier versions